# Writing and Reading to and from a binary file C language

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I was given an assignment to manage a sort of music store. In the database (which is saved as a .dat file) we have an artists name, and the album.

I'm having problems writing and reading the file.
First thing is, even if I don't write anything, just create the file, and then open the file in notepad, i see gibberish and letters in chinese or japanese.
Even if i write to the fail, or read from it using visual studio, this doesnt seem to change. Here's my code:

I opened the file with:

```
p=fopen("database.dat","w+");
```

The add item function:

```
void add_item(char* artist,char* record,FILE* p) //adds an item with artist and record to store
{
    item node;
    int item_size=sizeof(item);
    rewind(p);
    strcpy(node.artist,artist);
    strcpy(node.record,record);
    fwrite(&node,item_size,1,p);
    printf("Data added\n");
}
```

item is the struct that is used to define a single item in the store. it has 2 fields, string artist and string record.

```
typedef struct item
{
    char artist[100],record[100];
}item;
```

This is for reading:

```
void print_file(FILE* p) //print the entire file
{
    int size=sizeof(item);
    item node;
    rewind(p);
    while(!feof(p))
    {
        fread(&node,size,1,p);
        printf("%s - %s\n",node.artist,node.record);
    }
}
```

if i use print_file, i see gibberish, if i actually open the file with notepad, i see japanese.

Help! :D

edit: Just discovered something. If I add an item, and then read the file, i will read the item. But if i run the program again, and try to read the file immediatly, i see gibberish.

Comment: There are several problems. Just off the top of my head, one issue, examine your item struct (which you didn't show). `strcpy` copies until null But it's unclear how you have these strings defined. So that's a possible issue. Also, every time you call add_item, you're resetting the file pointer, so each write of an item is overwriting the previous one. And you don't show your file open request, so it's unclear whether you opened the file in binary mode or text mode.

Comment: Noted. Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed my original post so its clearer. I opened the file with p=fopen("database.dat","w+). all the strings are defined as char[100], and i removed the rewind as it was a mistake.

Comment: Try "w+b". Way back when I did C programming, "w+" for fopen defaulted to text, although it's possible it's not so in your case. Although your data has text, you're treating it as binary data in your code.

Comment: Still no good. If I run the program and enter 2 items, and then try to read them, i can. If however I try to open the file to read them, I see gibberish. And if i close the program and open it again, and try to read, it doesnt show anything. As if i didnt actually write to the file

Comment: Did you try writing and reading *a single `char[]`* first, before trying an `item`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with "w+", it will truncate existing file to zero length and open it for write & read.  When you run the program second time this is what happens and your read (before write) returns gibberish.
More on fopen [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html)

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the problem. Or well not problem. It's not avoidable

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing based on your symptoms that the strings are defined as `char*` and not `char[]`, which would be your problem. String IO on files doesn't work that way. Keep in mind that a string is actually of type `char*`, that is, a pointer to one or more 8-bit integers. When you write the string to the file, you're actually writing the value of the address itself, not the characters it points to.

You should use the `fprintf()` function to write strings to files:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/
And then `fscanf()` to read them:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

In general, if you're going to use a struct as a file format, you can't put pointers in the struct. You could put `char[]` values, because they aren't handled the same as pointers, but that would require a hard limit on string size. This is one of the reasons why structs as file formats are discouraged by some-- better to read and write the values one at a time, handling strings and so on appropriately.

The reason it works when you read the file back immediately (before quitting your program) is because that pointer address is still valid for that string. But the string itself never got written into the file.